# How to split Xtext grammar file into multiple ones?

Tags: dsl, xtext

I am building my first DSL with Eclipse Xtext. I would like
to be able to split the "main" Xtext file into multiple
ones, for "modularity", if you will. Is there an import mechanism
in Xtext files so that I can import those little Xtext files in the main one?
This is essentially, grammar rules reuse, I want to do
for the same language. I am not talking about reusing
rules from different DSLs. The same language, but I want
to split the big Xtext file to multiple ones and the main
one will "orchestrate" the whole grammar by importing the little
Xtext files.
Can I do that and how?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can only "mix in" one base grammar. In the [example](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/301_grammarlanguage.html#language-declaration) this is the `Terminals` part:

```
grammar org.example.domainmodel.Domainmodel
        with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
```

The complete documentation is [here](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/301_grammarlanguage.html#grammar-mixins) but basically there is no generic include mechanism.

Comment: aah. Pitty. ANTLR allows splitting *.g4 files and import them. Maybe Xtext will add that feature in the future. Thank you anyway